# Get Value from list using foreach

Tags: python, foreach

I am trying to get a value from a list using for each:

```
for Therepot, member in enumerate(pots[0]):
        TherePotValue = Therepot
```

pots[0] holds something like [4, 6, 2, 1, 8, 9]

Edit

---

To return the value i should point my variable TherePotValue to member and not the TherePot witch is the index.

Running a test:

TherePot = 0 , Member = 4

TherePot = 1 , Member = 6

TherePot = 2 , Member = 2

TherePot = 3 , Member = 1

TherePot = 4 , Member = 8

TherePot = 5 , Member = 9

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What is `TherePotValue` ?

Comment: `Therepot` is the index. The value in that index is `member`.

Comment: @That1Guy yes i think i'm pulling the index value, so Member is the value?

Comment: @That1Guy That's what enumerate does, but what is `TherePotValue` obviously will store the index, but what OP is trying to achieve with this is a mystery... What is "get 0 all the time" supposed to mean?

Comment: @jadkik94 I assumed (s)he was questioning the value 0, as they inform us that `pots[0]` is a list, and was only receiving 0. I'm very well aware of what enumerate does.

Comment: Sorry i'm very TherePotValue is my storage variable, and i'm trying to return the value of each item in the list and pass it to a function. the reason its always returning zero is because i said print TherePotValue in my first function witch was calling the index 0

Comment: you need to show more of what you are doing and what you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these examples will help you do what you want to do:

```
lst = pots[0]

# solution using a for loop
for i, member in enumerate(lst):
    # i is the position in the list
    # member is the data item from the list
    assert lst[i] == member  # cannot ever fail
    if member == the_one_we_want:
        break  # exit loop, variables i and member are set
else:
    # the_one_we_want was never found
    i = -1  # signal that we never found it

# solution using .index() method function on a list
try:
    i = lst.index(the_one_we_want)
except ValueError:
    # the_one_we_want was not found in lst
    i = -1  # signal that we never found it
```

EDIT: The comments made me realize that the `else` in the `for` loop could be confusing.

In Python, a `for` loop can have its own `else` case.  Raymond Hettinger has commented that he wishes the keyword had been something like `when_no_break` because the only time you use this `else` is with a `break` keyword!

If the `for` loop exits early, with the `break`, the `else` code does not run.  But if the `for` loop runs all the way to the end and no `break` ever happens, then at the end the `else` code runs.  Nick Coghlan calls this a "completion clause" to distinguish it from the "conditional else" from an `if` statement.

https://ncoghlan_devs-python-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html

It's sort of unfortunate that the `else` comes right after an `if` statement, because that might be confusing.  That `else` has nothing to do with that `if`; it goes with the `for` loop, which is why it indents the way it does.  (I do like that in Python you are forced to line things up when they go together.)

Comment: How lovely that you can (not) indent else like that!

Comment: @AndyHayden Just note that that `else` does not mean "do this if we didn't do anything in the loop" ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's very important that `pots[0]` actually has the value you think it does.  Consider the following code:

```
>>> pots = [[4, 6, 2, 1, 8, 9]]
>>> TherePotValue = 0
>>> for Therepot, member in enumerate(pots[0]):
        TherePotValue = Therepot
        print "(",Therepot,")", member
```

This produces:

```
( 0 ) 4
( 1 ) 6
( 2 ) 2
( 3 ) 1
( 4 ) 8
( 5 ) 9
>>> print TherePotValue
5
>>>
```

If you are seeing `0` I can only assume that `pots[0]` has only one element.

Comment: `If you are seeing 0 I can only assume that pots is not a sequence.` -- in which case, a `TypeError` would be expected

Comment: @JonClements, well technically the OP could be wrapping the enumeration in a `try` block and only seeing the initially defined value of TherePotValue, but I admit that is a stretch

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
    TherePotValue = len(pots[0]) - 1
```

so you are not doing anything with the loop other than what you do at the last iteration. Always getting 0 suggests that pos[0] has length 1.

Comment: Well - except for a length of 0, in which case the name won't be defined :)